# How to create an ObservableList based on a custom data structure like stack

Tags: java, data-structures, javafx, stack, javafx-8

For example, if you have an `ArrayList`, you can do the following:

```
ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
ObservableList<T> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);
```

Similarly, if I have a custom-made `Stack` instead of an `ArrayList`, how would I make an `ObservableList` off of that?

Comment: Are we talking `java.util.Stack` or a home-grown implementation? If it is home-grown, could you post its structure?

Comment: The [Javadocs for `ModifiableObservableListBase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ModifiableObservableListBase.html) show how to wrap an arbitrary structure to make it observable, for the case if your `Stack` is not a `Collection` implementation.

Comment: Also note that `FXCollections.observableArrayList(collection)` creates a new observable list, and copies the elements of the provided collection to it. The observable list in this case (unlike `FXCollections.observableList(list)`) is not backed by the provided list: changes to the observable list do not propagate to the provided list, and vice-versa. So all you need to replicate this behavior is a mechanism to get all the elements of your stack, as either a collection or an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to `implement` the `List` interface in your custom stack. As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-) there is an `FX.Collections#observableList(List<E>)` method provided.

So...

```
public class MyStack<T> implements List<T> {
    // Provide the list interface...
}
```

and pass it directly.